# How do we Riemann-integrate over subsets of the real line?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose we're high school teachers standing in front of a group of intelligent, logical and intellectually voracious 17 year olds. We've already defined the meaning of the notation $$\int_a^b f(x)dx$$ as a Riemann integral, e.g. using Darboux sums, and the students have learned how to compute some basic integrals using FTC.

We now wish to move to probability theory. If $f$ is the density function of some continuous probability distribution $\mathbf{P}$ on the real line, then for all sufficiently nice $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, we have $$\mathbf{P}(A) = \int_{x \in A} f(x)dx$$

Notice that this is an integral over a subset of the real line. So, we want to get down a definition that allows us to Riemann-integrate over subsets of the real line. The kids are smart, so the definition can be pretty sophisticated. But Lebesgue integrals are currently (just) out of reach, so it has be a Riemann-style definition.

> **Question.** How do we Riemann-integrate over subsets of the real line?

Comment: First extend the original definition to cover the whole real line. (Limit over compact intervals, ...) Then define the integral over a subset by multiplying the integrand with the characteristic function. Then prove consistency with the old definition.

Comment: @iolo, nice idea!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, extend the definition of the integral to cover integration over $( -\infty, \infty )$ by taking limits over compact intervals:

\begin{equation}
\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x) \text{d}x = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} \int\limits_{a_n}^{b_n}f(x) \text{d}x
\end{equation}

where $[a_n, b_n]$ is some exhaustion by compact sets (colourful language is always fun).
Then prove that the above is independent of the particular exhaustion for suitably nice functions.

**EDIT:** This point is crucial, because unlike compact intervals, continuity of $f$ is not enough to obtain a unique limit (think about principal values). You have to make clear that $f$ needs to decay fast enough at infinity (which is easy enough to picture though).

Now define

\begin{equation}
\int\limits_{x \in A}f(x) \text{d}x = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \chi_A(x) \cdot f(x) \text{d}x
\end{equation}

for subsets $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}$, where $\chi_A$ is defined as

\begin{equation}
\chi_A(x) = \left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       1 & : x \in A\\
       0 & : x \notin A
     \end{array}
   \right.
\end{equation}

Note, that you now have two definitions for intergration over intervals. So prove that they are equivalent.

Also give nice counterexamples where any of the above procedures fail, emphasizing the need of $f$ to be $\textit{suitably nice}$.

Comment: I love this idea. But one question that comes to mind is: do we really need to take a limit in order to define $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) dx$? I mean, there's already a limit embedded in the usual definition of the Riemann integral - can't we just take this limit "correctly" to define integrals with endpoints at infinity?

Comment: I believe the difficulty with your way of reasoning is the independence of the partition that is used. You do not have that for functions over the whole real line.

Comment: That makes sense. I think we'd have to send the partition toward each end of the real line at "equal speed" or else bad things would happen.

Comment: @goblin No, absolutely not! It has to be independent of the "relative speeds". Think about integrating $sin(x)$. With suitable relative speeds to the left and right, we can have the integral approaching $\textit{any real value we want or even diverge}$.

Comment: But $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \sin(x)$ doesn't exist. I'm not really following how this is an objection to the equal speed thing.

Comment: If you choose equal speeds, it will exist and equal zero, because $\int \limits_{-a}^{a} \sin(x) \text{d}x = 0$ for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Oh, I see. Perhaps what's needed is "equal speed from any central point", or something like that. So the integral of $\sin(x)$ doesn't exist because the integral of $\cos(x)$ doesn't, which is just a shifted version of $\sin$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60267/discussion-between-iolo-and-goblin).

Comment: when you say you think about principal values, do you mean these https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_value or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_principal_value ?